# Designing UITableView like iPhone iOS 7 Settings Page

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Does anyone have recommendations on the best way to design a UITableView that looks like the iOS 7 Settings View? Specifically, I'm focused on creating the sections with the thin gray separator lines and the separator heights.

Thanks![image]

Comment: Isn't this just a UITableView with the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve a settings controller, this is for you: https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit

[image: InAppSettingsKit]

Answer (score 0):

This is the new iOS7 style of `UITableView` with style `UITableViewStyleGrouped` 
Try it out